react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac , error on NativeProxyCommon and DevMenuUtils
reanimated is crashing with these errors
D:\Projects\To Delete\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\reactNativeVersionPatch\ReactHost\72\com\swmansion\reanimated\DevMenuUtils.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
private void addDevMenuOption(ReactApplicationContext context, DevOptionHandler handler) {
^
symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
location: class DevMenuUtils
D:\Projects\To Delete\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\reactNativeVersionPatch\ReactHost\72\com\swmansion\reanimated\DevMenuUtils.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
private void addDevMenuOption(ReactApplicationContext context, DevOptionHandler handler) {
^
symbol:   class DevOptionHandler
location: class DevMenuUtils
D:\Projects\To Delete\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\nativeProxy\NativeProxyCommon.java:85: error: addDevMenuOption(ReactApplicationContext,DevOptionHandler) has private access in DevMenuUtils
DevMenuUtils.addDevMenuOption(mContext.get(), this::toggleSlowAnimations);
^
D:\Projects\To Delete\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\reactNativeVersionPatch\ReactHost\72\com\swmansion\reanimated\DevMenuUtils.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
if (context.getApplicationContext() instanceof ReactApplication) {
^
symbol:   class ReactApplication
location: class DevMenuUtils
D:\Projects\To Delete\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\reactNativeVersionPatch\ReactHost\72\com\swmansion\reanimated\DevMenuUtils.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
final DevSupportManager devSupportManager =
^
symbol:   class DevSupportManager
location: class DevMenuUtils
D:\Projects\To Delete\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\NovacomApp V1.2.0.2\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\reactNativeVersionPatch\ReactHost\72\com\swmansion\reanimated\DevMenuUtils.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
((ReactApplication) context.getApplicationContext())
^
symbol:   class ReactApplication
location: class DevMenuUtils
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
6 errors
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

When i run my app using npx react-native run-android, The app crashes with errors. This happened after deleting Node modules and yarn_lock file
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
};


"react-native-reanimated": "^3.12.0", "react-native": "0.72.0",

Check in the node_modules folder which version you are installing. If not in package.json, try installing the corresponding version via npm
npm install react-native-reanimated@3.7.1

Make sure to delete the react-native-reanimated folder of node_modules before and that the package version is not locked in the package-lock.json/yarn.lock
This solved my issue
